# How to swap javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi have program that displays LINE & Column Chart.
Now what I want is that by default Line chart should get displayed.
I have achieved that.
But on button click I want that chart to get converted to column chart.
So I have both java script code in different function but I am not able to switch between them.
Also chart refresh rate is 1 second.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(setInterval);</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
var i   = 11400;
var j   = 11460;
var k   = 11120;
var l   = 11350;
      setInterval(function drawChart() {
k=k-20;
l=l+5;
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      i++],
          ['2005',  1170,      j--],
          ['2006',  660,       k],
          ['2007',  1030,      l]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      },1000)
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
setInterval(function drawMaterial() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Energy Level');

      data.addRows([
        [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8 am'}, 1, .25],
        [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '9 am'}, 2, .5],
        [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'10 am'}, 3, 1],
        [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '11 am'}, 4, 2.25],
        [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '12 pm'}, 5, 2.25],
        [{v: [13, 0, 0], f: '1 pm'}, 6, 3],
        [{v: [14, 0, 0], f: '2 pm'}, 7, 4],
        [{v: [15, 0, 0], f: '3 pm'}, 8, 5.25],
        [{v: [16, 0, 0], f: '4 pm'}, 9, 7.5],
        [{v: [17, 0, 0], f: '5 pm'}, 10, 10],
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Motivation and Energy Level Throughout the Day',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time of Day',
          format: 'h:mm a',
          viewWindow: {
            min: [7, 30, 0],
            max: [17, 30, 0]
          }
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Rating (scale of 1-10)'
        }
      };

      var material = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart'));
      material.draw(data, options);
    },1000)
</script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart" style="width: 550px; height: 350px"></div>
<button name="switch" value="switch">Switch Graph</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should just generate both, and have one hidden.  Turn on the hidden one, hide the visible one.  Much simpler than trying to rerun the data and construct a new chart.

Comment: I am new to java script so can you please upload the modified code?

Comment: Well, no, I'm not going to write it for you.  But I can explain how.  You have a DIV for your chart.  That one is done.  Make another one with the other kind of chart.  Set it to "display:hidden".  Use your switch function to hide one and shoe the other.

Comment: but it will use lots of RAM as well as CPU as I have 15-20 graphs to show and all with refresh rate of 1 Second so to load both graphs at a time and keeping them hidden will not be proper solutions. we can go with it if no proper solution found

Comment: If CPU and memory are an issue, then why are you doing it like this to begin with?  You must realize that graphs with a refresh rate of 1 second are a terrible load on your network and client machine both.  So even with one kind of chart, you're already going about this the wrong way.